# how to build a folder path in Unix shell scripting for any directory structure

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

My Application has a folder structure like

```
/PNRPHD1/ex1/11.txt

/PNRPHD1/ex1/ex2/11.txt

/PNRPHD1/ex1/ex2/ex3/23.txt

/PNRPHD1/ex1/ex2/34.txt

/PNRPHD1/ex1/ex3/sp4/sp3/4334.txt,
```

but **/PNRPHD1 is main folder**, within that folder I need to iterate every time and go to the last level and check if the file exists or not,in that Directory or not,
if File is the content of directory, then i need to build that path and come out of that loop. and I should have the above mentioned path as the output of the variable.

Note: **In the above directory structure, each directory can contain either a other Sub directory or a File, it wont have both**

Can any one suggest I was trying to do that in a IF loop, But that is getting too much of code, I wanted to implement with minimum code

```
DIR_REG = /PNRPHD1;
    ls -p $DIR_REG | while read -r dir
    do
        echo "directory under is  -- " ${dir} >>${DEBUG_LOG_FILE}
        BUP="/cygdrive/d/psoft/${PSFT_SID}/${dir}";

        ls -p $BUP | while read -r dir1
        do 
            if [ -f "${BUP}/${dir1}" ]; then 
                mkdir -p "${BUP}backup"
                echo "level of directory  -- " ${BUP}/${dir1} >>${DEBUG_LOG_FILE}
            else
                echo "level of directory  -- " ${BUP}/${dir1} >>${DEBUG_LOG_FILE}
            fi

        done

    done
```

I am looking for a better shell script and concise one, which does the required task..

Updated :
I am expecting the output of my loop should have a variable output in each iteration.
1st Case : /ex1/
2nd case : /ex1/ex2
3rd Case : ex1/ex2/ex3/
4th Case : /ex1/ex2/ex3/
5th Case : /ex1/ex3/sp4/sp3/

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the directory tree you require once. Then use `tar` to create a tar file. Any machine you require the same directory structure just unpack the `tar` file.

A manual page for tar can be found from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)

Comment: tar wont help me in this scenario, as I am not creating the same directory structure, I wanted to copy the file from the last level and paste it in a defined directory..

Comment: @gmhk - the question is not clear. Perhaps find, cp would work. Please give a better explanation what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to loop through the folder structure from /PNRPHD1/ and wanted to get the flder path till the end of the directory structure, like Variable A should have ex1, variable A should have the value ex1/ex2/, var A should have /ex1/ex2/ex3/ , etc... after iterating

Comment: @gmhk - Your comment does not make any sense. Please update your OP to give an example of a tree structure and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the find command 
find . -type f -print;
to list all the type of files

and

find . -type d -print;
to list all the type of directories

once we get the list of files or directories, use DirName command to get the path